# Perl: Pass one byte plus STDIN to another command

Tags: perl, io

I would like to do this efficiently:

```
my $buf;
my $len = read(STDIN,$buf,1);
if($len) {
    # Not empty                                                                                                          
    open(OUT,"|-", "wc") || die;
    print OUT $buf;
    # This is the line I want to do faster
    print OUT <STDIN>;
    exit;
}
```

The task is to start `wc` only if there is any input. If there is no input, the program should just exit.

`wc` is just an example here. It will be substituted with a much more complex command.

The input can be of several TB of data, so I would *really* like to not touch that data at all (not even with a `sysread`). I tried doing:

```
    pipe(STDIN,OUT);
```

But that doesn't work. Is there some other way that I can tell OUT that after it has gotten the first byte, it should just read from STDIN? Maybe some open(">=&2") gymnastics combined with `exec`?

Comment: what is the one byte for? jusr to trigger the reading ot the file? could be a signal instead?

Comment: @OlivierDulac As mentioned: The task is to only start wc if there is any input. If there is no input, the program should just exit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FIONREAD ioctl, mentioned in the *Perl Cookbook*, can tell you how many bytes are pending on a file descriptor *without* consuming them.  In perlish terms:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select qw( );    
BEGIN { require 'sys/ioctl.ph'; }

sub fionread {
    my $sz = pack('L', 0);
    return unless ioctl($_[0], FIONREAD, $sz);
    return unpack('L', $sz);
}

# Wait until it's known whether the handle has data to read or has reached EOF.
IO::Select->new(\*STDIN)->can_read();

if (fionread(\*STDIN)) {
    system('wc');
    # Check for errors
}
```

This should be very widely portable to UNIX and UNIX-like platforms.

Comment: It seems to work on systems having 'sys/ioctl.ph'. In my test it shows that this missing by default on  dragonfly hpux aix macosx openindiana netbsd  qnx scosysv solaris
unixware tru64
solaris-x86. Can we find a solution that is portable _without_ having root or the user install additional software?

Comment: @OleTange, `h2ph -d` and `@INC` should eliminate the need for root.  Regarding additional software, if you can install your script, you can typically generate and install the `.ph` file.  You could also do the hard work and ship your own mapping of `$^O` to FIONREAD values ... or just say that a previously generated `.ph` is a requirement of your software.

Comment: Can we do it on the fly? So the user will not need to change their system - neither as root nor as the normal user?

Comment: @OleTange, sounds like [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

The specific solution in which you're interested is impossible.

---

<s>As you surely discovered already, you can't determine if a file handle has reached EOF without reading from it.</s> [Apparently, [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29678548/589924)] `select(2)` will get you close. It will tell you that a handle has reached EOF or has data waiting, but it won't tell you which. This is why you're looking into alternate solutions. Unfortunately, the one you're looking into is just as impossible.

> *Is there some other way that I can tell OUT that after it has gotten the first byte, it should just read from STDIN?*

No. `OUT` isn't code; it doesn't read anything. It's a variable. Furthermore, it's a variable in the parent. Changing a variable in the parent isn't going to affect the child.

Maybe you meant to ask: Can one tell the *child program* to start reading from a second handle?

No, generally speaking. You can't go and edit another program's variables. The program would have to be specifically written to accept two file handles and read from one after the other.

Then again, it's possible to obtain a file name for an arbitrary file handle, so all we need is a program that is specifically written to accept two *file names* and read from one after the other, and that's quite common.

```
$ echo abcdef | perl -MFcntl -e'
   if (sysread(STDIN, $buf, 1)) {
      pipe(my $r, my $w);
      my $pid = fork();
      if (!$pid) {
         close($w);

         # Clear close-on-exec flag.
         my $flags = fcntl($r, Fcntl::F_GETFD, 0);
         fcntl($r, Fcntl::F_SETFD, $flags & ~Fcntl::FD_CLOEXEC);

         exec("cat", "/proc/$$/fd/".fileno($r), "/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDIN));
         die $!;
      }

      close($r);
      print($w $buf);
      close($w);
      waitpid($pid, 0);
   }
'
abcdef
```

(Lots of error checking needed.)

Above, `cat` was used an example where your program would be used, but that presents another solution: Why not just use `cat`? The overhead of `cat` should be quite minor for an IO-bound program.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd1 = shell_quote("cat", "/proc/$$/fd/".fileno($r), "/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDIN));
my $cmd2 = ...
exec("$cmd1 | $cmd2");
```

Comment: As I see you delegate to `cat` to touch every byte. The goal is to avoid touching every byte.

Comment: No, I don't.  I used cat as the example program like you used wc

Comment: That said, I really wonder what kind of overhead you think `cat` adds to an IO-bound program.

Comment: I replaced 'cat' with 'wc' and it does not do the same as my example: Your example does not pass the input on stdin, and it seems it only works on systems with /proc (i.e. no hpux, ultrix, openbsd, macosx).

Comment: It is unclear to me why you believe the program is IO-bound. My measurements tells me that the speed of Perl's sysread is in the same ballpark as cat, and using sysread will be a cleaner solution (i.e. no forking cat).

Comment: I explained in detail how the workaround works, and "passing the input to STDIN" is not even close. // If you have problems porting it, feel free to ask for help. // I don't know how you can think that writing several TB of data to a pipe is not IO bound. If you're saying it's CPU-bound (that it takes so much longer to generate the data that it takes longer to generate the data than to write it), then it doesn't change anything: `cat` will not add any noticeable overheard to an IO-bound program, and even less to a slower one.

Answer (score 1):

A child process is always given duplicates of its parent's file handles, so simply starting `wc` - either with backticks or with a call to `system` or `exec` - will cause it to read from the same place as the Perl process's `STDIN`.

As for starting `wc` only when there is something to read, it looks like you need [`IO::Select`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Select), which will allow you either to check whether a file handle has something to read, or to block until it *does* have something.

This program will check whether `STDIN` has any data waiting, and run `wc` and print its output if so.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select;

my $select = IO::Select->new(\*STDIN);

if ( $select->can_read(0) ) {
  print `wc`;
}
```

The parameter to `can_read` is a timeout in seconds. Passing a value of zero makes it return immediately, reporting *true* (actually it returns the file handle itself) if there is data waiting, or *false* (`undef`) if not.

If you don't pass a parameter then `can_read` will wait forever until there is something to read, so you can suspend your program and wait for data for `wc` by writing just

```
$select->can_read;
print `wc`;
```

or you could combine the construction of the object to make it even more concise

```
IO::Select->new(\*STDOUT)->can_read;
print `wc`;
```

Note also that `IO::Select` works fine with file descriptors too, and as the fileno for `STDIN` is zero, you could write

```
my $select = IO::Select(0)
```

but that isn't very descriptive and would need a comment to make sense

Comment: `can_read` returns immediately on EOF, just as if data was present, so that doesn't work. Or maybe you are trying to reimplement `-t STDIN`?

Comment: I just tested: `perl canread </dev/null` this starts `wc`. It should not as there is no data to read.

Comment: @OleTange: All you need to do is check for `eof` as well as `can_read`. i.e. `if ( $select->can_read(0) ) { print \`wc\` unless eof STDIN; }`

Comment: I tested: `cat empty | canread.pl` - works. `canread.pl < empty` - works. `canread.pl < non-empty` - works. But `cat non-empty | canread.pl` - does not work (it passes 0 bytes to `wc`). Tested on Cygwin. The solution must, unfortunately, be portable.

Comment: @OleTange: How are you running `wc`? It must be `system` or backticks.

Comment: I am using your code (canread.pl is your 7 lines of code above).

Comment: eof reads 8k from the handle as if you had called Perl's read